# Check if line in datafile contains an array element

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a file containing a list of keywords. I have a second datafile containing a few thousand rows of data. I have read the file containing keywords into an array, I would now like to take the first element in the array, loop through lines in the file and print any values that contain that array element. Then move onto the next element in the array and repeat the process.

Below is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible. Any help would be appreciated.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my $keywords= shift;
my $data= shift;

#reading in keywords file and storing in array
open (FH, "< $keywords");
my @keywords= <FH>;
close FH;

# now I want to iterate over the array and for each element loop through
# the datafile checking if the element exists in the line

open (DATAFILE, "< $data");
for my $element (@keywords) {
    for my $line (<DATAFILE>) {
        if ($line =~ /\Q$element\E/) {
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
close DATAFILE;
```

Comment: How big are your files? As a side-note, you should always check the success of calls to `open`, either by adding `use autodie;` to the top of your script or adding `or die $!;` immediately after the `open`, e.g. `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Failed to open '$file': $!";`

Comment: My keywords file could contain a few hundred lines, the datafile contains upto 50000 lines. Thanks for the validation tip, I have added those to the open and close statements for the files but just wanted to save on typing here!

Comment: You will only loop through the data file once, since you don't reset the filehandle to the beginning of the file after reading it. You can resolve this by [`seek`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)ing to the beginning of the file for each keyword, but your algorithm is pretty inefficient. You'll be doing on the order of 5 million comparisons, with lots of disk I/O. One alternate approach would be to store all of the unique words in the data file in a hash, along with an array of corresponding line numbers, and use hash lookups. This would use a fair amount of memory, though.

Comment: (My alternative solution assumes you're trying to match complete words. If you need the keyword `cat` to match lines like `cater` in addition to `rat cat bat`, you can't use a hash; in that case, it might be better to read the entire data file into a scalar and use a regex.)

Comment: Your subject line is half problem ***"line in datafile contains"*** and half solution ***"an array element"***. You are presuming -- wrongly in this case -- something about the solution, and it will cloud the vision of both yourself and others who aim to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should always check whether your file open succeeded and complain appropriately if it didn't.

```
open (FH, "< $keywords") or die "Failed to open $keywords: $!";
# ...
open (DATAFILE, "< $data") or die "Failed to open $data: $!";
```

Second, your `@keywords` array consists of strings with newline characters at the end, just as they appeared in the file.  You probably don't want that.  Do this instead to get rid of the newlines as you read the file:

```
chomp(my @keywords = <FH>);
```

Third, after you've read through the data file the first time through the `$element` loop, you're at the end of file, and reading from it again during successive `$element` loops will just return immediately.  The quickest fix would be to add `seek DATAFILE, 0, 0;` to the bottom of the `$element` loop.  That would move the file pointer back to the start of the file so you can read it again.

Finally, it would have been helpful if you had given examples of both files' contents and what output you expected your script to produce.

Another debugging tip: If I didn't understand why I wasn't getting all of the matches I expected, I would add print statements like this:

```
for my $element (@keywords) {
    print "Starting to search for <$element>\n";
    for my $line (<DATAFILE>) {
        print "Examining line <$line>\n";
        # ...
    }
}
```

That would have shown the newline character in `$element`, and you also wouldn't have seen `Examining line <$line>` after the first pass through the file.

Comment: @jm666 Yes, but I was trying to focus on the most important points.

Comment: thanks I have added your suggestions above and tested on a small subset of data and seems to return the results I want! Could you explain what the purpose of the 'seek' statement? Also, apologies for not including data samples, the data I have is sensitive so don't want to post it on the internet!

Comment: @Shaw There's nothing wrong with using made-up data that illustrates what you're working with.

Comment: I added some more comments.

Comment: This is a code review. There is [a site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1):

This program makes some assumptions about the input files (for instance, that the keywords file contains only a single word, and not a phrase containing spaces) but it is probably the fastest and most convenient way of achieving your goal

The keys in the keywords file are made unique and sorted in decreasing order of length (so that `off` isn't found when the string is `offer`) and all non-word characters are escaped using `quotemeta` so that they are matched verbatim instead of as part of an escape sequence

Then a regex pattern is built so that the keyword search can be optimised (since version 5.10 the Perl regex engine builds a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for a list of alternatives)

There is still the problem that if, say, `que` is a keyword but `antique` is not then the search will return a false positive. It could be improved by judicious use of the *word boundary* regex pattern `\b`, but that brings with it new questions, such as if `sign` is a keyword but `re-sign` is not, then again the search will return a false positive. Issues such as this are very sensitive to the individual dataset and a solution can't be generalised in the same way as the listed assumptions

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my ($keyword_file, $data_file) = @ARGV;

my $re = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $keyword_file;
  my %kw;
  /(\S+)/ and ++$kw{$1} while <$fh>;
  join '|', map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %kw;
};
$re = qr/$re/;

open my $fh, '<', $data_file;
/$re/ and print while <$fh>;
```